# How to handle loss function and log probabilities for neural network with multiple outputs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've implemented a custom environment in the style of OpenAi Gym environments in which I have shapes (circles, squares etc.) that I can move on a plane within a boundary. I want to apply reinforcement learning algorithms like REINFORCE on this problem and made my own custom reward function. But I now have trouble in designing the neural network to take a state and output an action.

To provide some background about my state-action settings. For the state I use a 2d-array describing the type of the shape (circle, square etc.) as one hot encoded array and the position (x,y coordinates of the edges of the bounding box) and the rotation of the shape (0 - 360) and have a row for each shape currently on the plane. For the action I have a 1d-array with the index of the shape to choose and the new position and rotation. I started with flattening the 2d-array into a single array, then having a hidden layer and then branching off into 3 outputs: Mu and Sigma for the probability distribution of the continuous output and probabilities for selecting the index of the shapes.

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, action_pair, input_shape):
        super().__init__('mlp_policy')

        self.input = kl.Input(shape=input_shape)
        self.flat = kl.Flatten()(self.input)
        self.hidden = kl.Dense(128, activation='relu')(self.flat)
        # action_pair is a tuple with the size of the categorical output and the continuous output
        self.index = kl.Dense(action_pair[0], activation='softmax', name='index')(self.hidden)
        self.mu_branch = kl.Dense(action_pair[1], activation='tanh', name='mu')(self.hidden)
        self.sigma_branch = kl.Dense(action_pair[1], activation='softplus', name='sigma')(self.hidden)


    def call(self, inputs):

        x = self.input(inputs)
        x = self.flat(x)
        hid = self.hidden(x)

        index = self.index(hid)
        mu = self.mu_branch(hid)
        sigma = self.sigma_branch(hid)

        return index_prob, mu, sigma
```

I don't know how I am supposed to handle log probabilities for the loss function, because normally I would use mu and sigma to compute the log prob, but now I have to also incorporate the categorical probabilities. Is it even right to predict the index, mu and sigma with a single neural net? I am just getting into RL, thanks in advance